# App crashes (parentActivityName)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-activity, parent

I have a problem with the arrow back button in the action bar, modifying the AndroidManifest.xml. The tag parentActivityName waorks with the first 2 activities but when i try to go back with the lastest activities the app crashes. Here is my manifest file.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/lupa"
    android:label="Movement Control"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Actividad"
        android:label="Panel Principal"
        android:parentActivityName=".EspMain">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".EspMain" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InfoPaciente"
        android:label="Informacion del paciente"
        android:parentActivityName=".Actividad">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Actividad" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Telefono"
        android:label="Telefono del cuidador"
        android:parentActivityName=".Actividad">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Actividad" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Monitor"
        android:label="Monitor de Movimientos"
        android:parentActivityName=".Actividad">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Actividad" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EspMain"
        android:label="Inicio de sesion"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EngMain"
        android:label="Login"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrincipalEng"
        android:label="Main panel"
        android:parentActivityName=".EngMain">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".EngMain" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PatientInfo"
        android:label="Patient information"
        android:parentActivityName=".PrincipalEng">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PrincipalEng" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NursePhone"
        android:label="Nurse phone"
        android:parentActivityName=".PrincipalEng">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PrincipalEng"
            android:value=".PrincipalEng" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EngMonitor"
        android:label="Movement monitor"
        android:parentActivityName=".PrincipalEng">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PrincipalEng" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Registro"
        android:label="Registro"
        android:parentActivityName=".EspMain"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="Register"
        android:parentActivityName=".EngMain">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.pabli.myapplication.EngMain" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have problems with the activities Telefono,InfoPaciente,Monitor.

The app goes like this MainActivity > EspMain > Actividad > Telefono/InfoPaciente/Monitor

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your android logcat?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Use this code for your main activity only. Remove for other.

Comment: I updated my code, but it stil doesnt work... i cant understand why it only crashes in the lastest activities.

Comment: What the name of your last activity?

Comment: Telefono is one of the last activities and there is where i ahve the problem. Last activities of the tree and where i have troubles are Telefono, InfoPaciente, Monitor

Answer (score 0):

You declared too many MAINs if you will.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Remove that code from all but the MainActivity and you should be in business.

Comment: I updated my code, but it stil doesnt work... i cant understand why it only crashes in the lastest activities.

Answer (score 0):

You have put

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

In all of your activity . That's the reason of crash .

So , put those intent filter only in your `Launcher Activity` in your case it might be main activity .

For more

[Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

[intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

Comment: OP has not category.LAUNCHER in all of the activities! 
"In android only one activity can be launcher activity" this is unfortunately not true. You are able to have 300 if you want to.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `.NameOfActivity` change it to :

```
android:parentActivityName="com.yourPackageName.app.EspMain" >
```

in all of your `Acitvities` you are using `parentActivityName`

Also I had a similar problem with a 5.0 version and I forgot to add this for each `Activity`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.packagename.app.YOUR_PARENT_ACTIVITY" />
```

Comment: FYI: the point at ".NameOfActivity", this is the short form for the package name. Having MAIN and DEFAULT, maybe has a reason for OP. I would only be irritated if there would be 11 LAUNCHER categories. (edit: I did not downvote,)

Comment: I had problems with broadcast receivers and so, and I did it and it solved my problem maybe it solves the problem too, by the way who downvoted me feel free to explain to me the reason, thanks :)

Comment: @JacksOnF1re Updated the question, you're right... that was an error :V